# How to insert a dynamically created p element into an main div which gets its inner text from a text box val every time a button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$button.on("click", function(e) {
    $para.html($evnt.val());

    if ($evnt.val() === "") {
        $evnt.css("border", "1px solid red");
        alert("Please enter some text in the textbox to add as task!!");
    } else {
        $main.prepend($para);
        $evnt.css("border", "none");

    }
    $evnt.val('');
});
```

$main >>> The main div,

$evnt >>> The input feild

I am new to jquery, tried this but every time i click the button the proviously entered text item gets replaced by the new one.

Comment: please share the html also

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: How are you creating this `$para`?

Comment: var $para = $("<p></p>", {
        addClass: "para"
    })

Comment: Can you provide your code on  what you have done so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the `p` element inside of the `on.click` handler.

```js
var $evnt = $('input');
var $main = $('#main');
var $button = $('button');

$button.on("click", function(e) {
    var $para = $("<p></p>", { addClass: "para" }); // New p element
    $para.html($evnt.val());

    if ($evnt.val() === "") {
        $evnt.css("border", "1px solid red");
        alert("Please enter some text in the textbox to add as task!!");
    } else {
        $main.prepend($para);
        $evnt.css("border", "none");

    }
    $evnt.val('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input value='' placeholder='Enter something!'>
<button>Add</button>
<div id='main'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Ele it worked, but how do i acess the $para globally if want add some new styles to it in a another eventhandler function e.g if i want to add a line through text decoration or remove it.

Comment: @HakimAarif because of that, you need to create the new elements inside of the handler to dynamically and specifically apply styles, attributes, Etc.

Comment: I mean, if i add a checkbox to each paragraph and attach a handler to the checkbox for marking the task as complete (line through it). Should i have to create that event handler inside this one or is there a way to create it separate. if so how do i access the $para variable or the checkbox created here inside that handler. Thank you again.